# HTTP POST from jquery to django running on google app engine

Tags: jquery, python, django

I'm not sure what is wrong..

On my html file I'm doing the following:

```
$.post("some_page", {
   param1: "something" , "param2": "something 2"
  }, function(data) {
   alert(data)
  }, "json");
```

On the python file qwerty.py to which I'm posting I have following:

```
def some_page(request): 

param1 = request.POST['param1']
param2 = request.POST['param2']
```

In the urls.py file I got the next line:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   (r"^some_page$", "views.qwerty.some_page"),)
```

After making HTTP POST there is internal server error, saying that request doesn't contain param1 neither param2(I tried to change the order of parameters), point to the line:

```
param1 = request.POST['param1']
```

in qwerty.py file.. What I'm doing wrong? Can you point me direction?

Thanks in advance,
Serhiy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't quote the keys in your $.post data dictionary as you did with 'param2' above.

```
$.post("some_page", {
        param1: "something",
        param2: "something 2"
    }, function(data) {
        alert(data)
    }, "json");
```

Also, when you attempt to get the value out of a dict in Python, you should either wrap it in a try/except clause or use the appropriate tools for the job.  For example:

```
param1 = request.POST.get('param1')
```

This will ensure that an exception isn't raised if `param1` doesn't exist in `request.POST`.  It will return `None` instead.

It might be that making some of the above changes fixes the issue for you - I hope.  It is sometimes difficult to help accurately when you only have a piece of the picture, though.

Comment: I tried to change, and there is an error:Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

'instancemethod' object is unsubscriptable.. The POST is still doesn't contain any params...

Comment: I managed to solve this changing $.post method to $.ajax method,making GET instead of POST. I also changed POST to GET in qwerty.py... But I would really like to know why $.post isn't working..